# Is it possible to upgrade the Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P5113) from 4.2.2 to a higher Android version?

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have an unrooted Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P5113) running Android 4.2.2

I want to upgrade the Android version there, however, I have no idea how.

Right now the tablet claims it is up-to-date, but we all know it is not - Android 4.2.2 is old.

Samsung Kies refuses to upgrade the firmware with the message "gt-p5113 does not support initialising".

Is there a way to upgrade the Android version on this tablet (while still keeping it usable, obviously) ? Preferably without rooting, but I will root it if there is no other choice.

I am OK completely resetting it.

Comment: Looking on [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-2/10-inch-development), it seems you could "upgrade" to higher version by flashing custom ROM. Some of the popular one are CyanogenMod. It definitely needs root though.

Comment: Well, nope there isn't any other choice other than rooting your device to flash your device with updated custom ROMs available. You are still running 4.2.2 means Samsung has abandoned your device and now the only way to remain updated is by rooting your device. Anyway like Andrew Said you can head over to the XDA Forum for knowing how you can do that !

Comment: Guys could you arrange a reply as an answer, so I could credit you? Also, if you target me to a specific "Rooting for Dummies" manual, that would simply be terrific. I am a pretty experienced Linux power user, if that can help.